# How to temporarily stop a control from being painted?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

We have a win control object which moves its clients to some other coordiantes. The problem is, when there are too many children - for example 500 controls - the code is really slow.
It must be because of each control being repainted each time I set Left and Top property. So, I want to tell the WinControl object stop being repainted, and after moving all objects to their new positions, it may be painted again (Something like `BeginUpdate` for memo and list objects).  How can I do this?
Here's the code of moving the objects; it's quite simple:

```
for I := 0 to Length(Objects) - 1 do begin
  with Objects[I].Client do begin
    Left := Left + DX;
    Top := Top + DY;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [LockWindowUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145034(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @kobik No, you should not call that API for this. It serves a completely different purpose.

Comment: Set the `Visible` property from your `WinControl` to `False` during child movement

Comment: @kobik: No! From somebody who should know: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx

Comment: @UliGerhardt and David, I know he knows, and I know that function is basically used for drag operations or a screen capture/spy utilities, but the simple fact it always seemed to work no matter what. `WM_SETREDRAW` as suggested by Raymond did not seemed to work for me in the past so I don't use it. and `DisableAlign`/`EnableAlign` does not eliminate the flicker but sure makes things move faster.

Comment: @kobik: I have found one glitch with `WM_SETREDRAW` in my code: In one instance I'm applying it to a whole form and that freezes the form. I had to put an alClient panel under all the components and `WM_SETREDRAW` that instead to fix it. What were your problems?

Comment: @kobik It's better to do it right than to break the rules.

Comment: @UliGerhardt, try `WM_SETREDRAW` (on Panel1.Handle) with [NGLN's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14522112/937125) and you will see what I mean. the buttons freeze and do not re-position (while LockWindowUpdate works just fine). maybe `ScrollWindowEx` is better for this situation. That depends on the real code and usage...

Comment: Seems Like the key with `WM_SETREDRAW` is to use `RedrawWindow` correctly after you re-enable painting for the control. I have updated [NGLN's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14522112/937125). I think now it should be perfect.

Comment: An alternative would be NOT to create or show all those controls. Create (or show) them only as you need them, as they are scrolled into the view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Cosmin Prund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521089/757830) explains, the cause for the long duration is not an effect of repainting but of VCL's realignment requisites at control movement. (If it really should take as long as it does, then you might even *need* to request immediate repaints).

To temporarily prevent realignment and all checks and work for anchors, align settings and Z-order, use [`DisableAlign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DisableAlign) and [`EnableAlign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.EnableAlign). And halve the count of calls to `SetBounds` by called it directly:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  for I := 0 to 499 do
  begin
    Control := TButton.Create(Self);
    Control.SetBounds((I mod 10) * 40, (I div 10) * 20, 40, 20);
    Control.Parent := Panel1;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  C: TControl;
begin
  // Disable Panel1 paint
  SendMessage(Panel1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, Integer(False), 0);  
  Panel1.DisableAlign;
  try
    for I := 0 to Panel1.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      C := Panel1.Controls[I];
      C.SetBounds(C.Left + 10, C.Top + 5, C.Width, C.Height);
    end;
  finally
    Panel1.EnableAlign;
    // Enable Panel1 paint  
    SendMessage(Panel1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, Integer(True), 0);
    // Update client area   
    RedrawWindow(Panel1.Handle, nil, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_UPDATENOW or RDW_ALLCHILDREN); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to make a single call to ScrollBy?

Comment: @David Yes, that would. Depending on the type of container control, it might need a subsequent call to `Invalidate` as well, but it sure would be much simpler. Although, in case of the need to move just a selection of all controls within the container (note that OP only moves the items in his `Objects` array), then I suppose this answer fits best.

Comment: I used parts of your code for updating a `TFlowPanel` child controls. I set caption of panel when there is nothing to show. But when I empty the caption `RedrawWindow` does not remove the previously painted text and I need to call an extra `Invalidate`. Should I pass another flag to `RedrawWindow` to cover that?

Comment: @saastn I'm unfamiliar with `TFlowPanel`. You could certainly try other flags. You could also try [my first edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14522112/1).

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption that the slowness comes from re-painting controls is probably true, but not the whole story. The default Delphi code that handles moving controls would delay painting until the next `WM_PAINT` message is received, and that would happen when the message queue is pumped, after you complete moving all the controls. Unfortunately there are a lot of things involved in this, that default behavior can be altered in many places, including Delphi and Windows itself. I've used the following code to test what happens when you move a control at runtime:

```
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 100 do
  begin
    Panel1.Left := Panel1.Left + 1;
    Sleep(10); // Simulate slow code.
  end;
end;
```

The behaviour depends on the control! A `TControl` (example: `TLabel`) is going to behave according to Delphi's rules, but a `TWinControl` depends on too many factors. A simple `TPanel` is not repainted until after the loop, in the case of `TButton` *on my machine* only the background is re-painted, while a `TCheckBox` is fully repainted. On David's machine the `TButton` is also fully repainted, proving this depends on many factors. In the case of `TButton` the most likely factor is the Windows version: I tested on Windows 8, David tested on Windows 7.

## AlignControl Avalanche

Anyhow, there's an other really important factor to be taken into account. When you move a control at runtime, all the rules for alignment and anchoring for all the controls need to be taken into account. This likely causes an avalanche of `AlignControls` / `AlignControl` / `UpdateAnchorRules` calls. Since all those calls end up requiring recursive invocations of the same, the number of calls will be exponential (hence your observation that moving lots of objects on a `TWinControl` is slow).

The simplest solution is, as David suggests, placing everything on a Panel and moving the panel as one. If that's not possible, and all your controls are actually `TWinControl` (ie: they have a Window Handle), you could use:

[BeginDeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [DeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [EndDeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hm... interesting test.

Answer (score 6):

I would put all the controls in a panel, and then move the panel rather than the controls. That way you perform the shift in a one single operation.

If you would rather move the controls within their container then you can use `TWinControl.ScrollBy`.

For what it is worth, it is more efficient to use `SetBounds` than to modify `Left` and `Top` in separate lines of code.

```
SetBounds(Left+DX, Top+DY, Width, Height);
```

Comment: `TScrollBox` moves all objects in no time. How does it do that?!

Comment: Effectively the same way. The controls inside the scroll box are not moved relative to the scroll box. Their `Left` and `Top` don't change when you scroll.

Comment: @David That's not true; `Left` and `Top` áre changed.

Comment: @NGLN It looks like the magic happens in `TWinControl.ScrollBy` where `FLeft` and `FTop` for the children are shifted. And then all updated in one go.

Comment: @Javid `TScrollBox`'s scroll bars call `TWinControl.ScrollBy` which uses [`ScrollWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787591(v=vs.85).aspx), and changes the private fields behind the `Left` and `Top` properties in case of childs being not `TWinControl`.

Comment: @NGLN: Yes you're right, I checked it out, it changes `FLeft` and `FTop` which is definitely faster than changing property.

Comment: So just call ScrollBy if that does what you want.

Comment: `ScrollBy` is much better but it's still slower than `TScrollBox` object.

Comment: If you'd given us a demo program, we could have optimised it.

Comment: I scroll panel up/down with all controls attached to it:  `OnScroll.. Panel.Top := Panel.Top + DeltaY`. Almost no flicker and very smooth moving all controls up and down.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up you should set the `Visible` property of you `WinControl` to `False` during child movement to avoid repainting.

Together with `SetBounds` you will get the best from moving the child controls.

```
procedure TForm1.MoveControls( AWinControl : TWinControl; ADX, ADY : Integer );
var
  LIdx : Integer;
begin
  AWinControl.Visible := False;
  try
    for LIdx := 0 to Pred( AWinControl.ControlCount ) do
      with AWinControl.Controls[LIdx] do
        begin
          SetBounds( Left + ADX, Top + ADY, Width, Height );
        end;
  finally
    AWinControl.Visible := True;
  end;
end;
```

**BTW** As David suggested, moving the parent is much faster than each child.

Comment: Could be a nice solution, BUT won't work if the controls are aligned. When you have them back visible, they will appear at a location different from the original one (when you made them invisible).